# tutorial vid was made in 2018 need help. supposed to be a switch

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
    Console.WriteLine(GetDay(0));

static string GetDay(int dayNum) {
            string dayName;
            switch ("dayNum") 
            {

                case 0 :
                    dayName = "Sunday";
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    dayName = "Monday";
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    dayName = "Tuesday";
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    dayName = "Wednesday";
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    dayName = "Thursday";
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    dayName = "Friday";
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    dayName = "Saturday";
                    break;
                defualt:
                    dayName = "invalid Day";
                    break;
            }
            return dayName;
```

im wracking my brain here all the code is except the number after case and its not registering the dayname that is supposed to be connected to the days
any help im doing a training video on youtube but its from 2018 and i think some of what hes teach has had subtle changes

Answer (score 1):

`switch ("dayNum")` .. the variable dayNum is suposed to be without quotes.

like this,

```
switch (dayNum)
```

What you are doing is a switch statement on a string "dayNum" which will only be true in `case "dayNum".. but in your case you need to use the variable being passed as the argument. So, remove the quotes.